# set property on grails.test.GrailsMock

Tags: spring, unit-testing, grails

I can't seem to figure out how to set a property on a mocked Service in a Service unit test. I've tried using the demand object and the `setProperty` method which seems to be gone from Grails 2.

```
@TestFor(SomeService)
@Mock([HelperService])
class SomeServiceTests {

void testDoSomething() {
    def helperService = mockFor HelperService

    // tried this, error in method being tested
    helperService.setProperty('propToSet',['a','b'])
    // tried this, error in test
    helperService.demand.propToSet = ['a','b']
    // tried this, error in method being tested
    helperService.demand.getPropToSet() {['a','b']}

    service.helperService = helperService

    assert service.doSomething('aa') != null
}
}
```

For most of these the error is `No such property: propToSet for class: grails.test.GrailsMock`, thrown from within the method I'm testing that needs it.  The second option above actually gives a hard error.  How do I set a property in a mocked Grails object?

Answer (score 0):

I also have not-that-good experiences with Grails mocking facilities. So I've been using GMock and happy with it. GMock plays well with all Grails tests including controllers, services and domain classes as well as Spock's specifications.

To use it, you simply put the following line into grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
    test 'org.gmock:gmock:0.8.2'
}
```

And this is the GMock version of your code.

```
@WithGMock
@TestFor(SomeService)
class SomeServiceTests {

    void testDoSomething() {
        def helperService = mock(HelperService)
        helperService.propToSet.returns(['a', 'b'])    
        service.helperService = helperService
        play {
            assert service.doSomething('aa') != null
        }
    }

}
```

Note that your mock codes will have affects only in the `play { }` block. So we need the block to wrap around assert statements.

Comment: I will have to check this out and let you know how it goes.